# How to build a nested query with the dynamic LINQ library

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, dynamic-linq

How can I build the following LINQ query with the Dynamic Linq library (System.Linq.Dynamic)?

```
var roles = rolesCollection.Where(r => r.AssignedUsers.Where(u => u.Name.FirstName == "Patrick").Count() > 0);
```

rolesCollection and AssignedUsers are collections which implement the IEnumerable interface.

I was thinking about doing something like this:

```
rolesCollection.Where("AssignedUsers.Where(\"Name.FirstName == 'Patrick'\").Count() > 0");
```

But that doesn't work. A ParseException with the message "No applicable aggregate method 'Where' exists" is thrown.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
rolesCollection
    .Where("AssignedUsers.Where(Name.FirstName == \"Patrick\").Any()");
```

or

```
var userName = "Patrick";
rolesCollection
    .Where("AssignedUsers.Where(Name.FirstName == @0).Any()", userName);
```

Comment: Dude you just saved me ! Cant figure out this linq and the docs aren't really complete. Where can i learn more about its queries ?

Comment: Check out the docs+example code at http://system-linq-dynamic-core.azurewebsites.net/html/a5ecbe15-aade-af7f-4860-6c5c412a34b4.htm