# How does nesting an OrderBy in a Dynamic Linq query work?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

I'm using Dynamic Linq and today I wanted to build a slightly more complex nested query:

```
"Composition
.Where(((ExpirationDate > DateTime.UtcNow.Date) && (ExpirationDate.Year != 9999)))
.OrderBy(\"ExpirationDate ASC\")
.Select(ExpirationDate)
.FirstOrDefault() == @0"
```

(the breaks are only there for readability in this post, not really there in code)

The query is held by a string variable and passed to this:

```
private static Func<IQueryable<T>, object, IQueryable<T>> CreateWhereExpression<T>(string whereClause) where T : class
{
     return (q, o) => q.Where(whereClause, o);
}
```

Which happily creates the Where expression. (note that whereClause contains the exact string above "Composition.Where....")
But as soon as it's time to execute, it will complain:

> No applicable aggregate method 'OrderBy' exists

So my question is, what am I doing wrong? How can I get the nested OrderBy to work?

Comment: Are you trying to parse `LINQ`? Dynamic LINQ doesn't support parsing own syntax.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get Dynamic Linq to parse the string as a Linq query. I also tried it with Linq syntax '.OrderBy(ExpirationDate)' but I got the same error. I'm trying to accomplish something similair to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314708/how-to-build-a-nested-query-with-the-dynamic-linq-library But with an orderby query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default DynamicLinq support a little functions for nested query to `IEnumerable` fields, all it defined in inteface `IEnumerableSignatures` like `Where`, `Any`, `Count` and etc, but don't have `Orderby`, `Select` or `FirstOrDefault` what you need.
So you can add it to this interface like

```
interface IEnumerableSignatures
{
    ....
    void OrderBy(object selector);
    void Select(object selector);
    void FirstOrDefault();
}
```

after that you need fix `ParseAggregate` method like this

```
Expression ParseAggregate(Expression instance, Type elementType, string methodName, int errorPos)
{
    ....
    if (signature.Name == "Min" || signature.Name == "Max" 
        || signature.Name == "OrderBy" || signature.Name == "Select" //add this for support OrderBy and Select that need two generic parameters
    )
    ....
}
```

at last next query will be work

```
"Composition
.Where((ExpirationDate > DateTime.UtcNow.Date) && (ExpirationDate.Year != 9999))
.OrderBy(ExpirationDate)
.Select(ExpirationDate)
.FirstOrDefault() == @0"
```

Comment: +1.  the version of DynamicLinq I was using vanished from Nuget and I had to pull in the base version, which is apparently missing this functionality.  thanks!