# No method 'SelectToken' exists on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable'

Tags: c#, json.net, dynamic-linq

I would like to run a `Json Object` through `DynamicExpression` but i am getting the error `"No method 'SelectToken' exists on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable'."`

the below rule i am trying to execute through DynamicExpression.

Rule: `JObject.SelectToken(\"$.Dosage\").ToString()==\"25\"`

my Json Object:

```
{
  "Dosage": 25,
  "Drug": "Indocin",
  "Patient": "David",
  "Date": "2019-05-22T22:06:50.4394817"
}
```

´Code:

```
//converted json to Json Object:

JArray jsonArray = JArray.Parse(jsonString);
JObject data = JObject.Parse(jsonArray[0].ToString());

bool r = CompareRules("JObject.SelectToken(\"$.Dosage\").ToString()==\"25\"", data);

public static bool CompareRules(string formula, params object[] objects)
{
    var result = false;
    try
    {
        var lstParams = objects.Select(o => Expression.Parameter(o.GetType(), o.GetType().Name)).ToArray<ParameterExpression>();
        var e = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(lstParams, null, formula);
        result = (bool)e.Compile().DynamicInvoke(objects.ToArray());
    }
    catch (TargetInvocationException) { }
    catch (KeyNotFoundException) { }
    catch (Exception ex) { }

    return result;
}
```

i expect the output of `JObject.SelectToken(\"$.Dosage\").ToString()==\"25\"` is `true` if the value matches otherwise false.

Comment: Why not get rid of all those error masking `catch` statements and see the actual error that occurs?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Dynamic Linq is the right choice here, as you can't use it the way you want to without really abusing* its source code (i.e., by adding conditions that only apply to `JToken`). Here's why:

Your exception stems from Dynamic Linq's `ParseAggregate` (you'd see it if you'd debug into Dynamic Linq source code).
This method assumes that the parsed dynamic method (in your case it's `SelectToken`) can be parsed into an `IEnumerable` extension method (e.g., `Where`).

However, `SelectToken` is not an `IEnumerable` extension method, but a simple instance method declared in `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken`. Therefore,  it's "not applicable", as the exception says.

For this reason, you'd also won't be able to use the steps given [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26079675/3002584), as they only apply for `IEnumerable` extensions methods.

You should go with standard reflection programming.

*Note that you're already using `ParseLambda` in an unconventional way, as the expression you pass it as the last argument is not a lambda.