# String based Dynamic Linq - Nested Where clause

Tags: c#, dynamic-linq

I'm doing string based Dynamic Linq and need to apply a nested where clause.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314708/how-to-build-a-nested-query-with-the-dynamic-linq-library) gets me half way there. However, the columns in two tables have matching ids. I need to be able to reference via an alias or other, like below:

```
rolesCollection
.Where("AssignedUsers.Where(AssignedUsers.TypId == rolesCollection.TypId).Any()");
```

Any idea how to accomplish this? I don't have the ability to pass in an object, this has to be purely a string based solution in the context of a genericized API search method. This is just an example of what I need ... I don't have the ability to join or anything via code. I'm looking for the solution in the string based portion of the example code.

Comment: is join an option?

Comment: If I can do the join via the string in the where clause there, yes. Good idea.

Comment: do you have the AssignedUsers object available ?

Comment: no, I need to work with the string portion of the example only.

Comment: where does assignedusers come from? need full example plz

Comment: This is an example based off of a prior accepted answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10314708/how-to-build-a-nested-query-with-the-dynamic-linq-library. It is just a theoretical scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AssignedUsers object should, in this theoretical example, have an AssignedUsers_Typ collection, and you can simply reference below, without having to reference the Typ columns from both tables.

```
   rolesCollection.Where("AssignedUsers_Typ.Any()");
```

I was able to resolve my issue using this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like that;

```
rolesCollection = rolesCollection.Where(x => assignedUsers.Any(t => t.TypId == x.TypId)).ToList();
```

Comment: No, I can only work within the string portion of the example above. I can't do traditional linq.